# Is this sentence past or future?

Tags: temps-grammatical

I read the following sentence in French:

> La loi sur les noms de famille a changé.

Does the above sentence mean that the law "has changed" or "is going to change"?

Answer (score 1):

It's the former:

> has changed

The form « a changé » is the « Passé composé ».